# Нарушение инкапсуляции в LayoutParams?

Tags: java, android

Есть такая штука, как `LayoutParams`, получить можно их у любого вью, например, если он находится в `LinearLayout`

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
```

Причём можно изменять параметры напрямую.

```
lp.height = 100;
```

Зачем? Неужели в гугле забыли про инкапсуляцию? Или здесь осмысленое применение? Какое?

Comment: Нашел такое обсуждение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33796162/why-does-some-android-code-have-public-fields Из объективных причин люди предлагают ограничение на количество методов.

Comment: Ну вообще то, есть альтернативная точка зрения на использование геттеров и сеттеров. Если они сводятся к this.height=height; и return height и это поведение никогда не изменится, то какой смысл в двух лишних методах?

Comment: Как же? Проверка на отрицание.

Comment: Очень сложно сказать действительно ли это поведение никогда не изменится. Но капля правды в описанном есть. А в случае изменения поведения можно полоать обратную совместимость. Ошушение что этим уже никто особенно не дорожит.